# Using jQuery with jQueryUI and HTML Forms?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery with jQueryUI . Everything looks cool , but Forms still look Ugly :(
Is there a simple way to make HTML Forms look really Cool like in Adobe FLEX without meddling with the jQUeryUI CSS Framework .

I mean some Instant Action Plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

[Uniform - Sexy forms with jQuery](http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform)